# Lucene.Net Search with "#" Not working

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I'm using lucene.net to search records in my website. I have lots of records with the special character hash ("#") like "C#", "C#.Net", etc...

But when I search using the term "C#" lucene is not returning any results. I have checked lucene Escaping Special Characters, but "#" is not in this characters list.

Is there a good way to search with the term "#" on Lucene.Net?

Comment: The escape characters vary from version to version. Have you tried escaping the hash sign with a \ anyway?

Comment: Yes I have tried with the escape sequence "\" but still its not working. And I'm using version Lucene 3.0.3.0

Comment: What analyzer did you use to index the data? Best guess is that you are using one that strips out `#` characters - you can't match them if they are not in your index. Please show your code.

Comment: I'm using StandardAnalyzer to index. Here is my code.
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, stopWords);
{
var nameParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, new[] { "CourseName"}, analyzer);  hits = searcher.Search(query, null, hits_limit, Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;
BooleanQuery query = query.Add(parseQuery(GetTerms(searchCriteria.CourseName), nameParser), Occur.MUST);
hits = searcher.Search(query, null, hits_limit, Sort.RELEVANCE).ScoreDocs;
var results = _mapLuceneToDataList(hits, searcher);
analyzer.Close();
searcher.Dispose();
return results;
}

Comment: I have verified the Lucene index file and the special character "#" is indexed. Only problem on searching it seems..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created my own Analyzer using the WhitespaceTokenizer and it wroked.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENENET-595

Thanks,
Singaravelu